# Method of analyzing circuits with diodes and opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, diodes, zener

This is an exercise from an electric circuits course I had on my first semester of university. We are asked to determine the output voltage \$V_o\$ when \$V_\text{in} = 667 \: \text{mV}\$. The diodes are ideal which means they have zero series resistance and thus, no voltage is dropped across them when they are forward biased. The zener diode has a zener voltage of \$V_z = 2 \: \text{V}\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmovaD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This problem clearly wants the student to use a simulator, because with one zener and one diode there are 6 possible cases to check to determine the state of the diodes. In addition, they have put an opamp in the circuit to make it even more daunting for first-year students. A simulation reveals that the output voltage is \$V_o = 2 \: \text{V}\$.

[image]

Now, using a simulator for this problem is perfectly valid.

What I'm interested in, is if there exists a method to solve this problem without using a simulator and without using the method of systematically assuming the state of the diodes and look for contradictions. A method where the solution just "falls out", whether it be node equations, FACTs, superposition, graphical analysis, or something else. Solutions that incorporate software tools like Maple/Sympy/Sage/... are very welcome.

Comment: No methods ... Just the "good" guess.

Answer (score 1):

> *The diodes are ideal which means they have zero series resistance and
> thus, no voltage is dropped across them when they are forward biased*

- The op-amp is configured as a non-inverting amplifier
- This means the output is positive with a gain of 1 or more
- The op-amp seeks to keep its input pins at the same voltage
- And, it can do this via a diode that is forward biased
- This means D1 and R2 may not play any role
- For now, they are removed from the analysis
- It then follows that the gain is 1 + R3/R1 = 3
- And the output voltage is 2.001 volts

Finally, as a double-check we test to see if the zener might be conducting. It's zener voltage is 2 volts but, at best the reverse voltage it sees is 1.334 volts so, it doesn't play a role and our original assumption to ignoe it correct.

This is how EEs analyse circuits.

Comment: Suppose R3 were 4 kohms instead.  Now you'd have to add some additional steps to check your assumption in bullet point 5, and re-work the problem with D1 and R2 put back in.

Comment: That isn't the question here so why are trying to invent a new scenario @ThePhoton

Comment: Because the question asks for a method to solve the problem, not just an answer for this specific set of resistor values.

Comment: @ThePhoton OK you convinced me.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis can be done by inspection, and reasoning from input to output, no need to assume output voltages ahead of time

- The +ve input voltage is 0.667 V
- Let's first assume the op-amp is operating 'properly', so we set the -ve input voltage to 0.667 V
- That means 0.667 V across R1
- So 667 uA flowing through R1
- None of which flows through the opamp -ve input
- So there's 667 uA in total flowing through the the feedback paths
- If it's all flowing through D1, then there's 667 mV across R2 and 2 V across D1, for an output voltage of 3.333 V
- If it's all flowing through D2, then there's 1.333 V across R3, for a total output voltage of 2 V
- 2 V is lower than 3.333 V, so it's all flowing through D2 and R3
- We have a consistent solution, so our assumption about the op-amp operating properly is valid, so there's no need to investigate solutions where the op-amp output is at one rail or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it "clearly wants the student to use a simulator". A quick look should tell you there are only two cases- Zener conducting or not.

Assuming balance, there is 667uA flowing through R1, so the output voltage must be higher than 0.667V and therefore D2 must be conducting. Let's assume the zener diode does nothing, then the voltage across R3 is double 0.667 or 1.334V. That's also the voltage across the Zener + resistor so indeed the Zener does not conduct.

(If R3 was, say, 4k then the voltage across R3 would be high enough for the Zener to conduct, so you'd recalculate, no big deal)

The output voltage is thus 0.666 + 1.334 = 2V.

Answer (score 0):

A person who has tinkered a while with simple (=no capacitors, nor other reasons of time dependency) opamp circuits notices in a second that with non-negative V1 one gets non-negative output Vo.

Vo stabilizes to a value which makes the minus input of the opamp to get the same voltage as V1. Let's call the voltage in the opamp's minus input Vx.

Let the Vo get higher gradually starting from zero. The zener diode starts to conduct when Vo-Vx passes 2 V. Before it Vx = Vo/3 due the voltage division. The limit is reached when Vo-Vo/3 = 2V i.e. Vo=3 V i.e. Vx = 1 V.

That means: Vx=Vin=0.667 volts is reached with no current in the zener diode. The output voltage is 3 x 0.667 V. That's 2 volts.